# checkbox value with if condition with jquery

Tags: jquery

Why does this if condition not work:

```
$("#btnSave").click(function () {
             $($('#<%=grdStudent.ClientID%>')).find("tr").find("#cbSelectAll:checked").each(function () {
                 if ($(this).find('td input[type=checkbox]:checked')) {
                     SaveData($('#<%=dlGroupID.ClientID%>').val(), $(this).find('td#LblStudentID'));
                     alert('تم اضافة البيانات بنجاح ');
                 }

             });

         });
```

The original table:
 $('#<%=grdStudent.ClientID%>').append("" + data.d[i].StudentID + "" + data.d[i].Name + "" +
 data.d[i].Phone + "" + data.d[i].Mobile + "" + data.d[i].Mobile2 + "
 ");
Any ideas?

Comment: Please format those code blocks...it's also riddled with syntax errors...

Answer (score 0):

You have loads of syntax errors in your code. Also the selector for `find` does not fit with the HTML you provided. I tried to fix it as good as possible:

```
$("#btnSave").click(function () {
    $('#<%=grdStudent.ClientID%>').find("tr").each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('td input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {
            SaveData($('<%=dlGroupID.ClientID%>').val(), $(this).find('td#LblStudentID').text());
        }
    });
});
```

Also see this http://jsfiddle.net/XXmjR/.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think your code suffered

If you have doubts on the format of your code, try [THIS online formater](http://jsbeautifier.org/) (works for HTML too !)

Here it is the fixed code ..

```
$("#btnSave").click(function (ev) {
  $('#<%=grdStudent.ClientID%>').find("tr").each(function (i, el) {
    if ($(this).find('td input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) { // adding .length property otherwise the test will always be true
      SaveData($('<%=dlGroupID.ClientID%>').val(), $(this).find('td#LblStudentID').text());
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Good point about `.length`, but the selector is still broken, isn't it?

Comment: Fixed ! thx for pointing that out ! I often see mistakes like forgetting about the length property `:p` Will I get an upvote for this .. ? ^^

Comment: previous code syntax was bad because i'm copy it and edit here my new code is

Comment: my previous code wrong because i'm copy it and edit here my new code i'm edit code above , please help